# how many clusters should I train for bag of words

Tags: matlab

I am learning BoW. But I do not know how many clusters I should train. The training size is N = 2666 videos.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard number of clusters to take. It depends on your set. If you take really good images for building the vocabulary maybe 150 or 200 will be ok. The best way is to start by a simple set of vocabulary and then grow it if it is successful.

It also depends on how many classifiers do you want to train after. The more classifiers the more words you will probably need.